# Where should you place external JS files in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, asset-pipeline

In Rails, EmberJS hijacks your `app/assets/javascripts` directory. It doesn't have to go there, but that's the convention.

```
+ app
  + assets
    + javascripts
      + components
      + controllers
      + helpers
      + mixins
      + models
      + routes
      + templates
        + components
      + views
      - app.js
      - application.js
      - router.js
      - store.js
```

Let's say I want to use [JavaScript MD5](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5). Where do I add the file? What directory?

To use the EmberJS gem we also have to remove the `require_tree` directive. So we end up with this:

```
# application.js.coffee
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require handlebars
#= require ember
#= require ember-data
#= require_self
#= require app

# for more details see: http://emberjs.com/guides/application/
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

# app.js.coffee
#= require ./store
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./controllers
#= require_tree ./views
#= require_tree ./helpers
#= require_tree ./components
#= require_tree ./templates
#= require_tree ./routes
#= require ./router
#= require_self
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember doesn't really hijack your JS folder. Simply put the code inside an "ember" folder to separate it from your own JS or other libraries you're using.

It should then look something like this (unsure about some of the ember files):

```
+ app
  + assets
    + javascripts
      + ember
        + components
        + controllers
        + helpers
        + mixins
        + models
        + routes
        + templates
          + components
        + views
      - app.js
      - router.js
      - store.js
    + jsmd5
      md5.js
    - application.js
```

Your application.js might look something like this:

```
# for more details see: http://emberjs.com/guides/application/
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

@import "jsmd5/md5.js"
```